# Aggregation Query Filtering

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation, opensearch

I have this query:

```
GET user_info,user_auth_cards_info/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "sorted_user_id": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "user_id",
        "size": 15
      },
      "aggs": {
        "filtered_names": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 2,
            "_source": {
              "includes": [
                "e_name",
                "cards_user_name",
                "status",
                "del_status",
                "user_id",
                "frog_id",
                "telphone"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

user_info has e_name,
user_auth_cards_info has cards_user_name

Issue I'm having is that I want to filter out data where e_name and cards_user_name don't start with a particular string ie "test" but if one of them do then they both should be in the aggregation. I can't figure out how I should be doing this